# How to send String values to another Activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

I want to send string values of latitude and longitude to another class but I'm a little bit confused about how to use it with put extra intent.

Here's my code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlacesMapActivity.class);

//Sending data to another Activity
String latitude = Double.toString(placeDetails.result.geometry.location.lat);
String longitude = Double.toString(placeDetails.result.geometry.location.lng);
i.putExtra("user_lat", latitude);
i.putExtra("user_lng", longitude);

startActivity(i);
```

Is it right if I try to retrieve the string value like this?

```
// Getting intent data
Intent i = getIntent();

// Users current geo location
String user_lat = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
String user_lng = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");
```

Please give me your opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the same name for the extra in put and in get. For example you put `user_lat` but then try to get `user_latitude`, this obviously won't work. Otherwise, it looks fine to me.

Note that you can put `double` values directly, there is no need to convert to a `String`. To get them back use `getDoubleExtra`.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question - yes, it is correct way to pass data from `Activity` to another one, but you have to remember that your `name` argument should be the same for putting and retrieving data.

Also the second way to do this is to use `getExtras()` method. In the second Activity, in which you want to retrieve data:

```
// Getting intent data
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

// Users current geo location
if(extras != null) { // Check if extras were found
   String user_lat = extras.getString("user_latitude");
   String user_lng = extras.getString("user_longitude");
}
```

The difference between both ways is:

- `getStringExtra()` method returns null if `String` with specified name could not be found
- `getExtras()` method returns null if no extras was found